# Django ForeignKey only delete "child" element

Tags: python, django

I've followed the starting tutorial and my admin page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGDtw.png)

I am trying to delete a choice by selecting the "Delete?" option and clicking "Delete", but after doing so it [prompts me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBHiT.png) to delete the entire question and its corresponding choices.  How can I only delete individual choices?

I've found that `on_delete=models.CASCADE` is most likely the culprit, and I've found [the alternatives](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), but none of these seem to just simply remove the Choice and revert the question to the state it was before I added the Choice.

I am a complete beginner and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to click "Save" to save changes made to the inlines, including deleting rows. "Delete" deletes the object you are editing, the question in this case

Comment: Cascade is the default behaviour and that will delete the related objects. Change the `on_delete` value if you'd like different behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) pointed out,

> You have to click "Save" to save changes made to the inlines, including deleting rows. "Delete" deletes the object you are editing, the question in this case

Thank you!